# Accessing iPhoto's saved on a DVD

Tags: photos.app, macos

I burned a lot of photo's to a DVD but it was an older version of iPhoto and now I can't view anything from the DVD on the new MAC.  Is there any way to access these photos? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Unfortunately, your question doesn't provide enough detail for us to help you. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer. For now, can you please edit your question (there's an _edit_ link below it) to add info such as: (1) Does the DVD appear on your desktop? If so, what do you actually see when you open the DVD? If not, have you tested the DVD on another computer? (2) What version of macOS are you running? (3) What new Mac do you own? (4) What DVD drive are you using?

Comment: How are you trying to view the photos on the DVD?  Are you in the newer Photos application?  See if anything on [this Apple page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204655) will help.